# Inner Join with loosely related tables and multiple relations

Tags: php, mysqli

In a table if I have:

```
FixtureID, HomeTeam, AwayTeam
```

Can I replace the ID that is related to HomeTeam and AwayTeam when it displays in the browser? HomeTeam and AwayTeam are both related to TeamID in the Teams table.

I want to show all fixtures and then replace both "TeamID" with "TeamName" so the name shows up instead of the ID?

So far I have:

```
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT fix.*, tea.*
    FROM Fixtures fix
    INNER JOIN Teams tea USING (TeamID)
SQL;
```

Then

```
echo '<p>Fixtures</p>';
echo '<div>'.$row['HomeTeam'].' v '.$row['AwayTeam'].'</div>';
```

EDIT:

Ok so I found a post that was similar to what I need and have tried the following:

```
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT fix.*, tea1.*, tea2.*
    FROM Fixtures fix
    INNER JOIN Teams tea1 ON fix.HomeTeam = tea1.TeamID
    INNER JOIN Teams tea2 ON fix.AwayTeam = tea2.TeamID
SQL;
```

However it's still just showing the team ID's rather than the names from the Teams table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself

```
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT f.*, t1.TeamName 'HomeTeam', t2.TeamName 'AwayTeam'
    FROM Fixtures f
    INNER JOIN Teams t1 ON f.HomeTeam = t1.TeamID
    INNER JOIN Teams t2 ON f.AwayTeam = t2.TeamID
SQL;
```